# why $(a+ P)(b+P)=ab +P?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $R$    be  a  commutative  ring .Preove that  an ideal $ P$  of $ R$ is a  prime  ideal   if and only  if  $R/P $ is  an integral domain

In the  proof it is   written that

> $(a+ P)(b+P)=P  \implies ab +P= P$ where $a , b \in R$

My confusion : why $(a+ P)(b+P)=ab +P?$

My attempt : $(a+ P)(b+P)= ab +aP  + Pb +P^2 \neq ab+P$

Comment: Elements in $R/P$ are of the form $a + P$. It's shorthand for the equivalence class which contains $a$. What you wrote is just the definition of the product for $R/P$.

Comment: If $I$ is a two-sided ideal of a ring $R$, the product of two elements $r_1+I$ and $r_2+I$ of the ring $R/I = \{r+I : r \in R\}$ is **defined to be** the element $r_1r_2+I$ of $R/I$. The equality $(a+ P)(b+P)= ab +aP  + Pb +P^2$ is non-sense.

Comment: okay @azif00 thanks

Comment: Do note that the proof that $(a+P)(b+P) = ab + P$ is well-defined amounts to $$ab + aP + Pb + P^2 \subseteq ab + P$$ but after that, we wouldn't usually go back to your form.

Comment: @azif00: I disagree. It's not nonsense. It's perfectly sensible and true. The issue is that $(a+P),(b+P)$ are multiplied as subsets of $R$, not elements of $R/P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\{(a + x)(b + y) : x, y \in I\}$ is generally not equal to $\{ab + z : z \in I\}$. For example, if we have $(2 + 6x)(2 + 6y)$, that's always a multiple of $4$, whereas $4 + 6z$ might not be divisible by $4$.

On the other hand, $\{(a + x)(b + y) : x, y \in I\}$ is always a subset of $\{ab + z : z \in I\}$. So we *define* the product in $R/I$ to be $(a + I)(b + I) = ab + I$. Then one needs to check that this product is well-defined. That is, if $a + I = a' + I$ and $b + I = b' + I$ then $ab + I = a'b' + I$. And this follows from the identity ($\forall x \forall y \exists z$) $$(a + x)(b + y) = ab + z.$$